# ItemReader can' find my csv file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i'm facing errors file not found

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist 
(reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource 
[file:///C:/Users/hello/Desktop/input/Ref_Org_Entite.csv]
```

this is my application.properties

```
ressource.path.InputDirectory=file:///C:/Users/hello/Desktop/input/
```

i tested even with only `file:C:/Users/hello/Desktop/input/` and
`file:/C:/Users/hello/Desktop/input/` and not working also

here is my ItemReader

```
 public class RefOrgEntitesItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<xxxxxx> {

        public RefOrgEntitesItemReader(String path) {
            this.setLinesToSkip(1);
            this.setResource(new ClassPathResource(path + "Ref_Org_Entite.csv"));
            ...
```

and even when i use  set Resources with `FileSystemResource` instedof `ClassPathResource` a get the same error
`.setResource( new FileSystemResource(path + "test.csv"));`

I'm under windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setResource( new FileSystemResource(path + "test.csv"))
```

update my application.properties without file:

```
ressource.path.InputDirectory=C:/Users/hello/Desktop/input/
```